# can't verify contract on etherscan (But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2))

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20

so i'm trying to verify a contract on rinkeby and ropsten...
getting the same error of

"Compiler debug log:
 Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI
 Found the following ContractName(s) in source code : AccessControl, Address, Context, ERC1363, ERC165, ERC165Checker, ERC20, ERC20Burnable, ERC20Capped, EnumerableSet, FIDAToken, IERC1363, IERC1363Receiver, IERC1363Spender, IERC165, IERC20, Ownable, Roles, SafeMath, TokenRecover
 But we were unable to locate a matching bytecode (err_code_2)"

i have triple checked the compiler version (0.6.6), and the optimization on/off option (off)
i'm still getting the error message again and again.

thing is... the exact same bytecode IS found below in the FIDAtoken bit...
below is the screenshot of the error.

Settings
Used: Remix ide, 
Compiler: 0.6.6, 
Optimization: off

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x096275f4bdb7310eaa209c042a15681314fa199c#code
this is the contract deployed addresss.

[image]

below is the contract code
https://github.com/fiatflux88/test/blob/master/tokencontract.sol

```
    pragma solidity 0.6.6;


contract Context {
    constructor () internal { }

    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address payable) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes memory) {
        this; // silence state mutability warning without generating bytecode - see https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2691
        return msg.data;
    }
}

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);


    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

library SafeMath {

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        require(c >= a, "SafeMath: addition overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return sub(a, b, "SafeMath: subtraction overflow");
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b <= a, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a - b;

        return c;
    }

    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {

        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        uint256 c = a * b;
        require(c / a == b, "SafeMath: multiplication overflow");

        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return div(a, b, "SafeMath: division by zero");
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b > 0, errorMessage);
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        return mod(a, b, "SafeMath: modulo by zero");
    }

    function mod(uint256 a, uint256 b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        require(b != 0, errorMessage);
        return a % b;
    }
}

library Address {

    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        bytes32 codehash;
        bytes32 accountHash = 0xc5d2460186f7233c927e7db2dcc703c0e500b653ca82273b7bfad8045d85a470;
        assembly { codehash := extcodehash(account) }
        return (codehash != accountHash && codehash != 0x0);
    }

    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint256 amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
}

contract ERC20 is Context, IERC20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;
    using Address for address;

    mapping (address => uint256) private _balances;

    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private _allowances;

    uint256 private _totalSupply;

    string private _name;
    string private _symbol;
    uint8 private _decimals;

    constructor (string memory name, string memory symbol) public {
        _name = name;
        _symbol = symbol;
        _decimals = 18;
    }

    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view virtual override returns (uint256) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(sender, recipient, amount);

        _balances[sender] = _balances[sender].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        _balances[recipient] = _balances[recipient].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: mint to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(address(0), account, amount);

        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.add(amount);
        _balances[account] = _balances[account].add(amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), account, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(account != address(0), "ERC20: burn from the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(account, address(0), amount);

        _balances[account] = _balances[account].sub(amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds balance");
        _totalSupply = _totalSupply.sub(amount);
        emit Transfer(account, address(0), amount);
    }

    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address");
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }

    function _setupDecimals(uint8 decimals_) internal {
        _decimals = decimals_;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual { }
}

abstract contract ERC20Capped is ERC20 {
    uint256 private _cap;

    constructor (uint256 cap) public {
        require(cap > 0, "ERC20Capped: cap is 0");
        _cap = cap;
    }

    function cap() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _cap;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

        if (from == address(0)) { // When minting tokens
            require(totalSupply().add(amount) <= _cap, "ERC20Capped: cap exceeded");
        }
    }
}

abstract contract ERC20Burnable is Context, ERC20 {

    function burn(uint256 amount) public virtual {
        _burn(_msgSender(), amount);
    }

    function burnFrom(address account, uint256 amount) public virtual {
        uint256 decreasedAllowance = allowance(account, _msgSender()).sub(amount, "ERC20: burn amount exceeds allowance");

        _approve(account, _msgSender(), decreasedAllowance);
        _burn(account, amount);
    }
}

interface IERC165 {

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) external view returns (bool);
}

interface IERC1363 is IERC20, IERC165 {

    function transferAndCall(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);

    function transferAndCall(address to, uint256 value, bytes calldata data) external returns (bool);

    function transferFromAndCall(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);

    function transferFromAndCall(address from, address to, uint256 value, bytes calldata data) external returns (bool);

    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);

    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint256 value, bytes calldata data) external returns (bool);
}

interface IERC1363Receiver {

    function onTransferReceived(address operator, address from, uint256 value, bytes calldata data) external returns (bytes4); // solhint-disable-line  max-line-length
}

interface IERC1363Spender {

    function onApprovalReceived(address owner, uint256 value, bytes calldata data) external returns (bytes4);
}

library ERC165Checker {

    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_INVALID = 0xffffffff;

    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC165 = 0x01ffc9a7;

    function supportsERC165(address account) internal view returns (bool) {

        return _supportsERC165Interface(account, _INTERFACE_ID_ERC165) &&
            !_supportsERC165Interface(account, _INTERFACE_ID_INVALID);
    }

    function supportsInterface(address account, bytes4 interfaceId) internal view returns (bool) {

        return supportsERC165(account) &&
            _supportsERC165Interface(account, interfaceId);
    }

    function supportsAllInterfaces(address account, bytes4[] memory interfaceIds) internal view returns (bool) {
        if (!supportsERC165(account)) {
            return false;
        }

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < interfaceIds.length; i++) {
            if (!_supportsERC165Interface(account, interfaceIds[i])) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function _supportsERC165Interface(address account, bytes4 interfaceId) private view returns (bool) {

        (bool success, bool result) = _callERC165SupportsInterface(account, interfaceId);

        return (success && result);
    }

    function _callERC165SupportsInterface(address account, bytes4 interfaceId)
        private
        view
        returns (bool, bool)
    {
        bytes memory encodedParams = abi.encodeWithSelector(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC165, interfaceId);
        (bool success, bytes memory result) = account.staticcall{ gas: 30000 }(encodedParams);
        if (result.length < 32) return (false, false);
        return (success, abi.decode(result, (bool)));
    }
}

contract ERC165 is IERC165 {

    bytes4 private constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC165 = 0x01ffc9a7;

    mapping(bytes4 => bool) private _supportedInterfaces;

    constructor () internal {
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC165);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view override returns (bool) {
        return _supportedInterfaces[interfaceId];
    }

    function _registerInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) internal virtual {
        require(interfaceId != 0xffffffff, "ERC165: invalid interface id");
        _supportedInterfaces[interfaceId] = true;
    }
}

contract ERC1363 is ERC20, IERC1363, ERC165 {
    using Address for address;

    bytes4 internal constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC1363_TRANSFER = 0x4bbee2df;

    bytes4 internal constant _INTERFACE_ID_ERC1363_APPROVE = 0xfb9ec8ce;

    bytes4 private constant _ERC1363_RECEIVED = 0x88a7ca5c;

    bytes4 private constant _ERC1363_APPROVED = 0x7b04a2d0;


    constructor (
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol
    ) public payable ERC20(name, symbol) {
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC1363_TRANSFER);
        _registerInterface(_INTERFACE_ID_ERC1363_APPROVE);
    }

    function transferAndCall(address to, uint256 value) public override returns (bool) {
        return transferAndCall(to, value, "");
    }

    function transferAndCall(address to, uint256 value, bytes memory data) public override returns (bool) {
        transfer(to, value);
        require(_checkAndCallTransfer(_msgSender(), to, value, data), "ERC1363: _checkAndCallTransfer reverts");
        return true;
    }

    function transferFromAndCall(address from, address to, uint256 value) public override returns (bool) {
        return transferFromAndCall(from, to, value, "");
    }

    function transferFromAndCall(address from, address to, uint256 value, bytes memory data) public override returns (bool) {
        transferFrom(from, to, value);
        require(_checkAndCallTransfer(from, to, value, data), "ERC1363: _checkAndCallTransfer reverts");
        return true;
    }

    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint256 value) public override returns (bool) {
        return approveAndCall(spender, value, "");
    }

    function approveAndCall(address spender, uint256 value, bytes memory data) public override returns (bool) {
        approve(spender, value);
        require(_checkAndCallApprove(spender, value, data), "ERC1363: _checkAndCallApprove reverts");
        return true;
    }


    function _checkAndCallTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 value, bytes memory data) internal returns (bool) {
        if (!to.isContract()) {
            return false;
        }
        bytes4 retval = IERC1363Receiver(to).onTransferReceived(
            _msgSender(), from, value, data
        );
        return (retval == _ERC1363_RECEIVED);
    }


    function _checkAndCallApprove(address spender, uint256 value, bytes memory data) internal returns (bool) {
        if (!spender.isContract()) {
            return false;
        }
        bytes4 retval = IERC1363Spender(spender).onApprovalReceived(
            _msgSender(), value, data
        );
        return (retval == _ERC1363_APPROVED);
    }
}

contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor () internal {
        address msgSender = _msgSender();
        _owner = msgSender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), msgSender);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }


    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(_owner == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }


    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract TokenRecover is Ownable {


    function recoverERC20(address tokenAddress, uint256 tokenAmount) public onlyOwner {
        IERC20(tokenAddress).transfer(owner(), tokenAmount);
    }
}

library EnumerableSet {

    struct Set {
        // Storage of set values
        bytes32[] _values;

        // Position of the value in the `values` array, plus 1 because index 0
        // means a value is not in the set.
        mapping (bytes32 => uint256) _indexes;
    }

    function _add(Set storage set, bytes32 value) private returns (bool) {
        if (!_contains(set, value)) {
            set._values.push(value);
            // The value is stored at length-1, but we add 1 to all indexes
            // and use 0 as a sentinel value
            set._indexes[value] = set._values.length;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _remove(Set storage set, bytes32 value) private returns (bool) {
        // We read and store the value's index to prevent multiple reads from the same storage slot
        uint256 valueIndex = set._indexes[value];

        if (valueIndex != 0) { // Equivalent to contains(set, value)

            uint256 toDeleteIndex = valueIndex - 1;
            uint256 lastIndex = set._values.length - 1;

            bytes32 lastvalue = set._values[lastIndex];


            set._values[toDeleteIndex] = lastvalue;

            set._indexes[lastvalue] = toDeleteIndex + 1; // All indexes are 1-based

            set._values.pop();

            delete set._indexes[value];

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    function _contains(Set storage set, bytes32 value) private view returns (bool) {
        return set._indexes[value] != 0;
    }

    function _length(Set storage set) private view returns (uint256) {
        return set._values.length;
    }

    function _at(Set storage set, uint256 index) private view returns (bytes32) {
        require(set._values.length > index, "EnumerableSet: index out of bounds");
        return set._values[index];
    }

    struct AddressSet {
        Set _inner;
    }

    function add(AddressSet storage set, address value) internal returns (bool) {
        return _add(set._inner, bytes32(uint256(value)));
    }


    function remove(AddressSet storage set, address value) internal returns (bool) {
        return _remove(set._inner, bytes32(uint256(value)));
    }

    function contains(AddressSet storage set, address value) internal view returns (bool) {
        return _contains(set._inner, bytes32(uint256(value)));
    }

    function length(AddressSet storage set) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return _length(set._inner);
    }

    function at(AddressSet storage set, uint256 index) internal view returns (address) {
        return address(uint256(_at(set._inner, index)));
    }


    struct UintSet {
        Set _inner;
    }

    function add(UintSet storage set, uint256 value) internal returns (bool) {
        return _add(set._inner, bytes32(value));
    }

    function remove(UintSet storage set, uint256 value) internal returns (bool) {
        return _remove(set._inner, bytes32(value));
    }


    function contains(UintSet storage set, uint256 value) internal view returns (bool) {
        return _contains(set._inner, bytes32(value));
    }


    function length(UintSet storage set) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return _length(set._inner);
    }

    function at(UintSet storage set, uint256 index) internal view returns (uint256) {
        return uint256(_at(set._inner, index));
    }
}

abstract contract AccessControl is Context {
    using EnumerableSet for EnumerableSet.AddressSet;
    using Address for address;

    struct RoleData {
        EnumerableSet.AddressSet members;
        bytes32 adminRole;
    }

    mapping (bytes32 => RoleData) private _roles;

    bytes32 public constant DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE = 0x00;

    event RoleGranted(bytes32 indexed role, address indexed account, address indexed sender);

    event RoleRevoked(bytes32 indexed role, address indexed account, address indexed sender);


    function hasRole(bytes32 role, address account) public view returns (bool) {
        return _roles[role].members.contains(account);
    }

    function getRoleMemberCount(bytes32 role) public view returns (uint256) {
        return _roles[role].members.length();
    }


    function getRoleMember(bytes32 role, uint256 index) public view returns (address) {
        return _roles[role].members.at(index);
    }


    function getRoleAdmin(bytes32 role) public view returns (bytes32) {
        return _roles[role].adminRole;
    }

    function grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual {
        require(hasRole(_roles[role].adminRole, _msgSender()), "AccessControl: sender must be an admin to grant");

        _grantRole(role, account);
    }

    function revokeRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual {
        require(hasRole(_roles[role].adminRole, _msgSender()), "AccessControl: sender must be an admin to revoke");

        _revokeRole(role, account);
    }

    function renounceRole(bytes32 role, address account) public virtual {
        require(account == _msgSender(), "AccessControl: can only renounce roles for self");

        _revokeRole(role, account);
    }

    function _setupRole(bytes32 role, address account) internal virtual {
        _grantRole(role, account);
    }

    function _setRoleAdmin(bytes32 role, bytes32 adminRole) internal virtual {
        _roles[role].adminRole = adminRole;
    }

    function _grantRole(bytes32 role, address account) private {
        if (_roles[role].members.add(account)) {
            emit RoleGranted(role, account, _msgSender());
        }
    }

    function _revokeRole(bytes32 role, address account) private {
        if (_roles[role].members.remove(account)) {
            emit RoleRevoked(role, account, _msgSender());
        }
    }
}

contract Roles is AccessControl {

    bytes32 public constant MINTER_ROLE = keccak256("MINTER");
    bytes32 public constant OPERATOR_ROLE = keccak256("OPERATOR");

    constructor () public {
        _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, _msgSender());
        _setupRole(MINTER_ROLE, _msgSender());
        _setupRole(OPERATOR_ROLE, _msgSender());
    }

    modifier onlyMinter() {
        require(hasRole(MINTER_ROLE, _msgSender()), "Roles: caller does not have the MINTER role");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOperator() {
        require(hasRole(OPERATOR_ROLE, _msgSender()), "Roles: caller does not have the OPERATOR role");
        _;
    }
}

contract FIDAToken is ERC20Capped, ERC20Burnable, ERC1363, Roles, TokenRecover {


    bool private _mintingFinished = false;

    bool private _transferEnabled = false;

    string public constant BUILT_ON = "https://vittominacori.github.io/erc20-generator";

    event MintFinished();

    event TransferEnabled();

    modifier canMint() {
        require(!_mintingFinished, "BaseToken: minting is finished");
        _;
    }

    modifier canTransfer(address from) {
        require(
            _transferEnabled || hasRole(OPERATOR_ROLE, from),
            "BaseToken: transfer is not enabled or from does not have the OPERATOR role"
        );
        _;
    }

    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint8 decimals,
        uint256 cap,
        uint256 initialSupply,
        bool transferEnabled,
        bool mintingFinished
    )
        public
        ERC20Capped(cap)
        ERC1363(name, symbol)
    {
        require(
            mintingFinished == false || cap == initialSupply,
            "BaseToken: if finish minting, cap must be equal to initialSupply"
        );

        _setupDecimals(decimals);

        if (initialSupply > 0) {
            _mint(owner(), initialSupply);
        }

        if (mintingFinished) {
            finishMinting();
        }

        if (transferEnabled) {
            enableTransfer();
        }
    }

    function mintingFinished() public view returns (bool) {
        return _mintingFinished;
    }

    function transferEnabled() public view returns (bool) {
        return _transferEnabled;
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 value) public canMint onlyMinter {
        _mint(to, value);
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public virtual override(ERC20) canTransfer(_msgSender()) returns (bool) {
        return super.transfer(to, value);
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public virtual override(ERC20) canTransfer(from) returns (bool) {
        return super.transferFrom(from, to, value);
    }


    function finishMinting() public canMint onlyOwner {
        _mintingFinished = true;

        emit MintFinished();
    }

    function enableTransfer() public onlyOwner {
        _transferEnabled = true;

        emit TransferEnabled();
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual override(ERC20, ERC20Capped) {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: What constructor arguments did you use?

Comment: used the ones in FIDAcontract    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint8 decimals,
        uint256 cap,
        uint256 initialSupply,
        bool transferEnabled,
        bool mintingFinished

Comment: What values did you use? Did they match the ones calculated by etherscan? I tried to follow etherscan wizard and constructor's parameters looks suspicious. For example strings parameters are encoded as an offset that is multiple of 32, and etherscan showed a bunch of random numbers instead.

Comment: below are the values i used. 

tried different values, changing the cap/mint/name/symbol/etc but still getting the same issue for some reason. 

NAME: FIDA
SYMBOL:FIDA
DECIMALS:18
CAP:100000000000000000000000000000000
INITIALSUPPLY:100000000000000000000000000000
TRANSFERENABLED:true
MINTINGFINISHED:false

Comment: You can use abi.hashex.org to encode those parameters, it should start like `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001200000000000000000000000000000000000004ee2d6d415b85acef81000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001431e0fae6d7217caa0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006224649...`

Comment: that worked! oh my god.... been trying so many variations of it... but that worked like a charm.
thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Currently etherscan verify smart contracts is not that friendly, If you are using truffle and smart contract is complicated involving many imports of library etc, or compilers settings are different like optimize enabled and runs set to not default value. Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-flattener Flattener concats solidity files from Truffle and Buidler projects with all of their dependencies If you still get some compilation warning like in my case I am using pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2. I just removed it from other files except for the main file which I was deploying in the flattened version, and it worked well and deployed my contract

For more information on how to use truffle-flattener check out "https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-verify-and-publish-on-etherscan-52cf25312945#"

Answer (score 0):

During verification of a smart contract in etherscan you should be confident about the use of compiler version during deployment.
Try to remember these things:

- Which solidity compiler version was used during the deployment of the contract
- Was the optimization enabled during deployment or not
- Any constructor argument passed during the deployment or not

During verification of smart contract you will need to check above options, otherwise it will not generate required bytecode and fail to verify.

I have had the same error and the solution was as follows:

I realized that when it returns that error it is because it is not taking which version of Smart Contract is being used (Open Zeppelin version) so I realized that it is necessary to go to the repository and see the latest version being used, i.e. .... Normally we do this

```bash
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```

or

```bash
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol;
```

But when we do our flatten calling the libraries that way we get the error.

The correct way to do it to be able to verify our smart contract without any problem is the following:

```bash
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.3.0/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```

or

```bash
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.3.0/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol;
```

That is to say our Open Zeppelin imports that we are using must be versioned for it we go to the [repository](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts) and we see the [tags](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tags) that will give us a guide of the current version.